# rails 3 : paperclip : undefined method logo

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, undefined, ruby-on-rails-3.2

In model I have something like

```
has_attached_file :logo, something_here
```

Code/ Uploading logo is working fine, but I need dimensions before uploading the logo.
So when I am using geometry, error is thrown for

```
undefined local variable or method 'logo' for #<Class:0xbfabbc0>
```

Any idea how to solve this? Or is there any other way to get the dimension before storing the data.

Answer (score 1):

You can hook to `after_image_post_process`. Here is working code from one of my projects:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :image
  after_image_post_process :save_thumb_file_size

  def save_thumb_file_size
    self.thumb_file_size = self.image.queued_for_write[:thumb].size if self.image.queued_for_write.key?(:thumb)
    return true
  end
end
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error. 'undefined method "logo" for #<Class:0xbdfee30>'

Answer (score 1):

Did you generate a migrations related to this field?

```
rails generate paperclip photo logo
```

and run rake db:migrate?

Comment: Yes, all fields are there in database. Successfully uploading the logo but when I try to get dimensions before saving, it throws the error.